# Vue change image with button

Tags: image, vue.js, vuejs3

```
const question = ref(false)
const changeQuestion = ref(false)

const changeQuestionButton = computed(() => {
  if (!changeQuestion.value) {
    return ['item.qimage']
  } else {
    return ['item.aimage']
  }
})
```

```
<a @click="question = true" class="card-footer-item">Question</a>

                <V-Modal
                  :open="question"
                  :title="item.name"
                  size="big"
                  actions="center"
                  @close="question = false"
                >
                  <template #title>
                    <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
                  </template>
                  <template #content>
                    <img :src="changeQuestion" />
                  </template>
                  <template #action>
                    <V-Button raised>Question</V-Button>
                    <V-Button
                      color="primary"
                      @click="changeQuestionButton = true"
                      raised
                      >Answer</V-Button
                    >
                  </template>
                </V-Modal>
```

By default the modal should show "item.qimage". Upon clicking the Answer button it should change the image to "item.aimage".

Currently it is not showing any image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are mixing up `changeQuestion` and `changeQuestionButton` in the template

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code you use `changeQuestion` for `src` of your imgage:

```
<img :src="changeQuestion" />
```

But in your function `changeQuestionButton`, where you want to return the `src` of the image it´s called, as quoted, `changeQuestionButton`:

```
const changeQuestionButton = computed(() => { //
  if (!changeQuestion.value) {
    return ['item.qimage']
  } else {
    return ['item.aimage']
  }
})
```

So `src` will not get any kind of path, because `changeQuestion` with `const changeQuestion = ref(false)` wont return anything like that.